# Break main function that contains "while True" with "return" from a subfunction

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I want to run a Python program function from a main function that controls the program function with

```
while True:
```

I'm led to believe this is good practice. I thought a return call in the program function would break me out, but I get stuck in an infinite loop. Typing "n" should break the loop - how do I do it and is this a sensible thing to do?

```
def main():
    while True:
        runPgm()

def runPgm():
    while True:
        a = str(input("Input?: "))
        if a == 'n':
            break
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have _two_ `while True` loops and you're only breaking out of one. You do not need both.

Comment: The problem is that you also run a `while True`-loop in your `main`-function, so you call the `runPgm`-function over and over again. This second function actually `break`s and `return`s, but immediately is called again in `main`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

You just need one infinite loop

```
def main():
    runPgm()

def runPgm():
    while True:
        a = str(input("Input?: "))
        if a == 'n':
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because your `break` statement (and subsequent `return`) just exits the current call to the `runPgm` function. But this returns you to the loop in `main`, which is never broken out of.

In general you can do "multiple breaks" like this by setting a Boolean flag to say you've want to do a further break, which is checked in the outer loop. However, in your case I think the easier solution is simply to only use one of the loops, not both. Just get rid of the `main` function entirely and call `runPgm` instead!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things for you in this.

1. Use single `while True` loop.
2. rather `break` just use `return` here because function exits as soon as return is reached.

see below python3 code example.

```
def main():
    print(runPgm())

def runPgm():
    while True:
        a = str(input("Input?: "))
        if a == 'n':
            return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The original source for my initial code is the pygame manual, the answers here show that I don't need to follow that method. However, I'm still unsure why the example in pygame resolves itself. But that's beyond the scope of this question and I'm satisfied I don't need to implement it.